# s3 link expire with aws-sdk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

i have been using gem 'aws-sdk' for uploading the file with rails, now i getting the created link,  basically this link will expire after one hour(i think thats default), but i need to give this link as public, so is there anyway to prevent the link from expire? as i tried like this

```
AWS.config(:access_key_id => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                  :secret_access_key => 'XXXXXXX')
s3 = AWS::S3.new
my_bucket = s3.buckets['xxx/xxxx/xxxx']
object = my_bucket.objects[filename]
puts object.url_for(:read).to_s
```

Comment: Is your bucket set to public? if so you only need to give the URL as:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket]/[key]

Comment: now its not public, now i am getting the url like this https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/report_01Nov14%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM_06%3A59%3A20%20PM.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxx&Expires=1414857564&Signature=xxxxxx
will it work when set it as public?

Comment: try building the URL string yourself, that is why the bucket names have to be unique.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to tell you to give permission to your files as well. I've done it in Python and used this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063673/how-can-i-programmatically-check-amazon-s3-permissions-with-boto)

Comment: Actually i put the expire here, and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

**Set your file access permission as public read**

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('akid', 'secret'),
region: 'us-west-1'
)

obj = s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key')
obj.upload_file('/source/file/path', acl:'public-read')
obj.public_url
```

[This link will help you](https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1K43Z7KXHM5D5/Uploading-Files-to-Amazon-S3)